# The timer in Tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I tried to use **time.sleep(1)**, but this causes the Tkinter window to hang, please help **so that the counter goes**.

```py
from tkinter import *
import time
def timer():
    d = 60
    while d:
        m, s = divmod(d, 60)
        mo = 'Время:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(m, s)
        tablo['text'] = mo
        window.after(1000, timer)
        d-=1
    tablo['text'] = 'Время: 00:00'
window = Tk()
window.geometry('900x600')
tablo = Label(text='', font="Courier 20 bold")
tablo.place(x=10, y=10)
tablo['text'] = "Время: 60"

start = Button(text="start", command=timer, width=10, font="Courier 15 bold")
start.place(x=300, y=10)
def _():
    window.quit()
exit = Button(text="exit", command=_, width=10, font="Courier 15 bold")
exit.place(x=600, y=10)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to modify the `timer` function, make `d` global, remove the `while` and have it call itself when it hasn't reached 0 yet.

```py
d = 60
def timer():
    global d
    m, s = divmod(d, 60)
    mo = 'Время:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(m, s)
    tablo['text'] = mo
    d-=1
    if d != 0:
        window.after(100, timer)
    else:
        tablo['text'] = 'Время: 00:00'
```

using `time.sleep` causes the GUI to hang, the proper way as outlined is to have the function call `after` on itself with a certain delay.

just note that the delay is **always more than the specified time**, your function will take longer than 1 minute to finish, so you should use the `time` module to calculate how much time is actually left.

Comment: line 22, in <lambda>
    start = Button(text="start", command=lambda: timer(60), width=10, font="Courier 15 bold")
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: timer() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: @toyotaSupra your modification requires you to use `window.after(100, lambda: timer(d))` and make `d` an **argument** of the function.

Comment: You'right thank.

Answer (score 0):

A method I learnt to repetitively call a function in Tkinter without interfering with the functionality of the app is to use the `frame.after(milliseconds, function)` method.

This is an example that can be used to count the number of seconds passed from the execution of the program

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       self.title("Seconds Counter")
       self.geometry("500x500+100+100")
       self.second_shower = Label(self, text = "0")
       self.second_shower.pack()
       self.seconds_past = 0 #Number of seconds past from start of program
       self.timeadd()
       self.mainloop()
       
    def timeadd(self):
        self.seconds_past += 1
        self.second_shower.config(text = str(self.seconds_past))
        self.after(1000, self.timeadd)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    global root
    root = Application()
```